# Chrome is redirecting all HTTP requests to a given server to a different port

Tags: networking, google-chrome, intranet

I was playing with some configurations for my home intranet and toyed with a few different non-standard port configurations. Along the way, Chrome seems to have gotten one of the configurations stuck in its head and won't let it go.

Specifically, accessing one of my servers at the regular :80 redirects to :99 (one of the configurations I played with and later removed). Other browsers aren't playing this game so it has to be something to do with Chrome retaining previous routing.

I've tried in Canary & IE (which weren't exposed to the test configurations) and both resolve the request correctly without swapping ports on me.

I'm at a loss and really frustrated. Any thoughts on how I can tell Chrome to reset itself without having to do a full re-install. Also, even with a full re-install, I'm not convinced that would resolve the issue if Chrome has let this issue make its way into my user data...

Comment: Interestingly, following the restarting Chrome instructions from that question didn't work, but clearing browsing data did. I flagged as duplicate.